# There is a proxy error im getting while running a flutter project on VScode

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed"

This is the error im getting while using flutter run command on the terminal.

Comment: Show the content of your main.dart Is it the default app?

Comment: yes its the default app that flutter opens with. I ran the app for the first time and i got the above error

Comment: UPDATE: I reinstalled Android Studio and the error got fixed